# Can I format a variable in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way of formating a variable?

For example, I'd like to automate the creation of a variable named *M_color*, where *M* is a string of value "bingo". The final result would be *bingo_color*.
What should I do if the value of M changes during the execution?

Comment: It's best not to rely on dynamic variable names. This leads to dangerous pitfalls like in PHP's `$$` variable variables... Just bad. Please consider using dictionary keys as suggested by other respondents.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution for this kind of problem is to use dictionaries:

```
color_of = {}
M = "bingo"
color_of[M] = "red"
print(color_of[M])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 'variable' can be an attribute of an object, you could use [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
class Color(object):
    pass

color = Color()

attr_name = '{foo}_color'.format(foo='bingo')
setattr(color, attr_name, 'red')
```

Beyond that, you're looking at using [eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: You could also do `globals()[attr_name] = 'red'` instead of `eval`, but I wouldn't recommend either.